# $P_{X1,X2}(x_1,x_2)={x_1x_2 \over 36}$ find joint and marginal of $Y_1$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let$$P_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)={x_1x_2 \over 36}, \text{ }x_1,x_2=1,2,3$$
$$Y_1=X_1X_2,Y_2=X_2$$
Find:

1) The joint PMF of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$

2) The marginal PMF of $Y_1$

What I got:
$$ P_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)={y_1 \over 36}, y_1=y_2,2y_2,3y_2, y_2=1,2,3 $$

Is this correct? and is there a way to get a formula for $P_{Y_1}(y)$?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y_{1}=X_{1}X_{2}\in\left\{ 1,2,3,4,6,9\right\} $ with:

$p_{Y_{1}}\left(1\right)=P\left\{ X_{1}=1\wedge X_{2}=1\right\} =\frac{1}{36}$

$p_{Y_{1}}\left(2\right)=P\left\{ \left[X_{1}=1\wedge X_{2}=2\right]\vee\left[X_{1}=1\wedge X_{2}=2\right]\right\} =p_{X_{1},X_{2}}\left(1,2\right)+p_{X_{1},X_{2}}\left(2,1\right)=\frac{4}{36}$

et cetera.